# What is the appropriate kernel for the i7-4770K CPU?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm attempting to install Centos 6.5 and Ubuntu 13.10 via VirtualBox and I seem to be getting conflicting issues.

I first tried installing the x86_64 version, which notified me that I needed the i686 version of the kernel. A quick Google search showed another person with the same problem and the suggested course of action was to install the i386 version. This led to the message

" This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae. 
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU"

Comment: Seems like it's supported: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_haswell_linux&num=1 & http://www.pcper.com/news/General-Tech/How-well-does-Haswell-do-Ubuntu

Comment: What's the base OS that virtualbox is running on? Perhaps you need the x86_64 version of VirtualBox on your base OS.

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=58582
I had not selected 64 bit from the Virtualbox menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=58582

"When you define a new VM, you must check the "Ubuntu 64bits" option under the Version drop-down menu."

I had not selected 64 bit from the Virtualbox menu.